# Cookie appear on Nth reload

Tags: javascript, cookies, refresh, reload, session-storage

I want to have a cookie that stores a unique message to appear on the 13th reload/refresh of a page. I want to use javascript cookies for this instead of sessionStorage or localStorage. What is the best way to do this? Thanks!

Edited: I have an array that reloads a randomized image and caption on refresh. I want to implement a cookie through javascript that when the array has reloaded all content, another image will appear, alerting the user that they have viewed all the content. Currently the images repeat, but ultimately, on the thirteenth time the viewer visits my page, I want them be able to the image that alerts them that they have viewed all content.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HANNAH</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var cookie = document.cookie;
if (cookie.indexOf('visited=', 0) == -1) {
var expiration = new Date();
expiration.setDate(expiration.getDate()+1);
document.cookie = 'visited=14;expires=' + expiration + ';path=/';

var element = document.getElementById('finish');
element.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#photos").hide();
});

var work = new Array; workcap = new Array

work[0] = "0.jpg"; workcap[0] = "IVY Cook Branding Guide";
work[1] = "1.jpg"; workcap[1] = "Digital Tools Cover Page";
work[2] = "2.jpg"; workcap[2] = "5x8 Notebooks Branding Guide";
work[3] = "3.jpg"; workcap[3] = "Materials & Tools Vinyl Installation";
work[4] = "4.jpg"; workcap[4] = "Mouse Minutes Logo Design";
work[5] = "5.jpg"; workcap[5] = "Feministic Fairy Dust Heirarchy Design";
work[6] = "6.jpg"; workcap[6] = "3D Type Advertisement";
work[7] = "7.jpg"; workcap[7] = "3D Type Fishbowl Installation";
work[8] = "8.jpg"; workcap[8] = "Friend-Love Book Jacket";
work[9] = "9.jpg"; workcap[9] = "Hand Rendered Original Alphabet";
work[10] = "10.jpg"; workcap[10] = "Initial Brick Typography Cover";
work[11] = "11.jpg"; workcap[11] = "Nike Ekin Pitch Deck";
work[12] = "12.jpg"; workcap[12] = "American Cancer Society Pitch Deck";


var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*13)


</script>
</head>
<body class="subpage">

    <!-- Header -->
        <header id="header">
            <div class="logo"><a href="index.html">HANNAH NOWAK <span>work</span></a></div>
            <a href="#menu">MENU</a>
        </header>

    <!-- Nav -->
        <nav id="menu">
            <ul class="links">
                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="resume2.html">RESUME</a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
                <li><a href="narrative3.html">CODE WALKTHROUGH</a></li>
                <li><a href="email.html">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    <!-- One -->
        <section id="One" class="wrapper style3">
            <div class="inner">
                <header class="align-center">
                    <p>RANDOMIZED PHOTO GALLERY</p>
                    <h2>PAST WORK</h2>
                </header>
            </div>
        </section>

    <!-- Two -->
        <section id="two" class="wrapper style2">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="content">
                        <header class="align-center">
                            <p>Reload page to see a random piece of my work</p><br>
    <div id="content">
       <img src="0.jpg" id="visible" height="50%" width="50%">

       <div id="caption">
       IVY Cook Branding Guide
       </div>

    </div>


    <div id="photos">
        <img src="0.jpg" id="thumb" alt="thumb">
        <img src="1.jpg" id="thumb" alt="thumb">
        <img src="2.jpg" id="thumb" alt="thumb">
        <img src="3.jpg" id="thumb" alt="thumb">
        <img src="4.jpg" id="thumb" alt="thumb">
        <img src="5.jpg" id="thumb" alt="thumb">
        <img src="6.jpg" id="thumb" alt="thumb">
        <img src="7.jpg" id="thumb" alt="thumb">
        <img src="8.jpg" id="thumb" alt="thumb">
        <img src="9.jpg" id="thumb" alt="thumb">
        <img src="10.jpg" id="thumb" alt="thumb">
        <img src="11.jpg" id="thumb" alt="thumb">
        <img src="12.jpg" id="thumb" alt="thumb">
<script>
document.querySelector("#visible").src = [number] + ".jpg";
document.querySelector("#caption").innerHTML = workcap[number];
</script>

                            </div>
                        </header>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

    <!-- Footer -->
        <footer id="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="icons">
                    <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/blcdesigns/" class="icon fa-instagram" class="icon fa-instagram" target="_blank"><span class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-envelope-o"><span class="label">Email</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </footer>

    <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollex.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), as asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: I want to have a cookie that stores a unique message to appear on the 13th reload/refresh of a page. I want to use javascript cookies for this instead of sessionStorage or localStorage. What is the best way to do this? Thanks! @FrankerZ

Comment: @FrankerZ I attempted to use the 'visited' attribute but I don't think I am using it in the right regards: <script type="text/javascript">
    
var cookie = document.cookie;
if (cookie.indexOf('visited=', 0) == -1) {
    var expiration = new Date();
    expiration.setDate(expiration.getDate()+1);
    document.cookie = 'visited=14;expires=' + expiration + ';path=/';

    var element = document.getElementById('finish');
    element.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>

Comment: Edit your original post, and post what you've tried, and what you've researched.

Comment: @FrankerZ Okay, thank you!